# Openshift Authorize Access denied

Tags: jenkins, oauth, openshift

My environment is openshift enterprise 3.4, I installed jenkins and the pod it's running on my project oes, when I trying to access http://jenkins.mydomain.com, it appears login with openshift page, then click the "Login with OpenShift" button, I got below errors: Did I missed any settings? Any advise will be appreciated!

> "error":"server_error","error_description":"The authorization server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.","state":"MmVkOTVjMWItODYwNC00"

Here is my oauthConfig in master-config.conf:

```
oauthConfig:
    assetPublicURL: https://openshift-master.anim.odw.com.cn:8443/console/
    grantConfig:
    method: auto
identityProviders:
    challenge: true
    login: true
    mappingMethod: claim
    name: htpasswd_auth
provider:
    apiVersion: v1
    file: /etc/origin/master/htpasswd
    kind: HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider
```

Here is the pod logs:

```
Apr 12, 2017 3:15:48 AM org.openshift.jenkins.plugins.openshiftlogin.OpenShiftOAuth2SecurityRealm populateDefaults
INFO: OpenShift OAuth: provider: OpenShiftProviderInfo: issuer: https://openshift-master.mydomain.com:8443 auth ep: https://openshift-master.mydomain.com:8443/oauth/authorize token ep: https://openshift-master.mydomain.com:8443/oauth/token
Apr 12, 2017 3:15:48 AM org.openshift.jenkins.plugins.openshiftlogin.OpenShiftOAuth2SecurityRealm populateDefaults
INFO: OpenShift OAuth returning true with namespace oes SA dir null default /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount SA name null default jenkins client ID null default system:serviceaccount:oes:jenkins secret null default eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNl3WNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJvZXMiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlY3JldC5uYW1lIjoiamVua2lucy10b2tlbi1mYmhjcCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY491bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50Lm5hbWUiOiJqZW5raW5zIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQudWlkIjoiNzFjYWEwYjItMTY5MC0xMWU3LWE2ZDktMDAxYTRhMTYwMTU2Iiwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtOnNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Om9lczpqZW5raW5zIn0.hnC-s2rXKFpF6xfhTI9-TJXDMkW6KU3DN6xQBWppj5xf98itR38eJwe3s4fUr3XWrXs_ipXXu14hnQTEykUCpNNGFuxxfNy6moOSThqSClsGojo4S1mdJ921_COFUnFWyP1H_ZMGZbw8GyPAcwKnjaZo253mDN8RlAWegcHry-noQuDkOfiNjXL1xiDu7ZeDTwmYome_-6xHpgBv0KbhqKjs7L6PilxpTo2QMjb7zOoJY0VShM4hb84oinQJ62m18Vxf-U-oZQs40QosnFGQFHRb9Jt3sQZzY1kYrp6UZHsg3_O-JvII1QaU02r4-2Ly7CqNIsDrO0OFj1tR4N4CEw redirect null default https://openshift-master.mydomain.com:8443 server null default https://openshift.default.svc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure jenkins to use single admin password as in documentation:

> JENKINS_PASSWORD   Password for the 'admin' account when using default Jenkin authentication.

See: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I set the OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH value to false, then I'm able to use 'admin' account to login Jenkins. But how to make jenkins to use openshift authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered is related to something being wrong in the OAuth flow.  This is most likely caused by having a misconfigured Jenkins service account.  Try to log in again, and see what the OpenShift API master logs say during that time (run it at `--loglevel=100`).

Comment: Added Jenkins to cockpit-oauth-client list, then restart the openshift master service, now the authentication error is gone. But Jenkins also lost openshift authentication, it required jenkins's admin to login.

Comment: @CarolLi Are you using one of the [Jenkins example templates](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/jenkins)?  These catch most configuration errors.

Comment: LOL, yes, I'm using jenkins-ephemeral. Which version would you recommend?

Comment: Any of those should work fine, granted you would want persistent to actually save data.  Can you output the yaml of the SA and capture the master logs from when you try to log in.